# Django rest-auth custom login form - not recognising inputted email: "Must include \"email\" and \"password\"."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-rest-auth, django-login

I wrote a very simple custom login form over the `rest-auth` `LoginView` like below:

### view

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

    def get(self, request):
        form = CustomUserLoginForm()
        print(form.get_user())
        return render(request, "api/test_template.html", context={"form": form})
```

### form

```
class CustomUserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

### template

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

            <div>
                <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">Email: </label>
                <input type="email" {{ form.email }}>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">password: </label>
                <input type="password" {{ form.password }}>
            </div>

            <button style="background-color:#F4EB16; color:blue" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        Don't have an account? <a href="/register" target="blank"><strong>register here</strong></a>!
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my `settings.py` i am making sure that the email is required and username is not:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
 "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

 # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
 "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

When I go to enter my email and password and then submit the form, Django rest-auth framework gives the below error:

[image]

As a test, I then input the same email address in the provided field in the browserable API and I manage to log-in successfully.

Why does rest-auth not recognize the email from my custom template? I bet the error has to do with my `{{form.email}}` not being implemented correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django default Authenticaiton form shows username rather than email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942640/django-default-authenticaiton-form-shows-username-rather-than-email)

Answer (score 0):

Following this solved the issue: [django default Authenticaiton form shows username rather than email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942640/django-default-authenticaiton-form-shows-username-rather-than-email/57942948#57942948)

This workaround involved removing the lines in settings.py shown above. and assigning the `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` in `models.py` in users app as stated in:
https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username